# Catch multiple types of errors in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

If I define custom error classes like this:

```
class MyCustom Error extends Error{ }
```

How can I catch multiple errors like this:

```
try{

  if(something)
    throw MyCustomError();

  if(something_else)
    throw Error('lalala');


}catch(MyCustomError err){
 

}catch(err){

}
```

?

The code above does not work and gives some syntax error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) recommends using an `if/else` block inside the `catch` statement. This is because it is impossible to have multiple `catch` statements and you cannot catch specific errors in that way.

```js
try {
  myroutine(); // may throw three types of exceptions
} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof TypeError) {
    // statements to handle TypeError exceptions
  } else if (e instanceof RangeError) {
    // statements to handle RangeError exceptions
  } else if (e instanceof EvalError) {
    // statements to handle EvalError exceptions
  } else {
    // statements to handle any unspecified exceptions
    logMyErrors(e); // pass exception object to error handler
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is weakly typed. Use `if (err instanceof MyCustomError)` inside the catch clause.